# Fraction in \pmod bracket

Tags: math-mode, fractions, displaystyle

I want to put a fraction into the `\pmod` brackets in math mode, i.e

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[x\equiv y\pmod{\frac{a}{b}}\]
\end{document}
```

However, the brackets don't become bigger, just like

```
\left( \right)
```

to fit with the fraction. How to fix it?

Comment: Please post an MWE - a small complete compilable document - so folks here can just cut and paste to work on it.

Comment: @EthanBolker: I posted an MWE.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the approach of `mathtools` with `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,xparse}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\parens{(}{)}
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\pod}{sO{}m}{%
  \allowbreak
  \if@display
    \mkern 18mu
  \else
    \mkern 8mu
  \fi
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\parens*{#3}}{\parens[#2]{#3}}%
}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\pmod}{sO{}m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\pod*{{\operator@font mod}\mkern 6mu#3}}
    {\pod[#2]{{\operator@font mod}\mkern 6mu#3}}%
}

\begin{document}
\[
x\equiv y\pmod*{\frac{a}{b}}
\]
\[
x\equiv y\pmod[\Big]{\frac{a}{b}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that you can use `\pod` with the same syntax as well (which omits the “mod”).

Comment: How can I modify `\pmod*`? It originally shortens the horizontal space between the congruence and the modulo brackets.

Comment: @user109351 I didn't touch the spacing in any way. There is no `*`-form for it, as it is provided by `amsmath`.

Comment: For example, I tried `x\equiv y\pmod*{n}` in displayed math mode but the space between `x\equiv y` and `\pmod*{n}` is the same as when I replaced `\pmod*` by `\pmod`. However, when I tried it inline the space was shortened.

Comment: @user109351 That's wanted and has nothing to do with the redefinitions.

Answer (score 1):

The below thing also works fine, though its **bmod**, and not **pmod**, still

```
\text{something} \equiv 13 \left(\bmod \dfrac{545\ell^{45}}{541p^P{p-1}}\right)
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thank you :) @Mensch