# Problem of writing mod in congruence with brackets and fractions

Tags: math-mode, lyx, modules

I want to write this: `a\pmod{\frac{a}{b}}` -
But the size of the brackets don't fits the fraction:

[image]

What can I do to fix it?
I see the answer here [Fraction in \pmod bracket](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317783/fraction-in-pmod-bracket) but I'm using LyX so I don't know how to do it at Lyx (is there other way?)

*(at inline mode it's fine, but I need it at display mode)*
Thank you!

P.S. It's OK to do it without `pmod` but its need to look the same :)

Comment: Can you add some code to your preamble with Lyx?

Comment: @Bernard - Yes...

Comment: You should use `$a \pmod{\tfrac{1}{b}}$` instead (this requires the use of [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these lines to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{xpatch} 
\xpatchcmd{\pod}{(#1)}{\left(#1\right)}{}{}
```